# strpos in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, strpos

Is there a  native Emacs Lisp function that behaves like [`strpos()` in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)? It should return the position of first occurrence of the given string in current buffer. Function `search-forward` is nice, but it modifies the character position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
;; does not modify match-data
(string-match-p (regexp-quote "string") (buffer-string))
```

or

```
;; does modify match-data
(string-match (regexp-quote "string") (buffer-string))
```

But those calls make a copy of the string, which isn't practical.  A better solution would be to use this:

```
(defun my-strpos (string)
  "mimic strpos"
  (save-excursion
    (save-match-data
      (goto-char (point-min))               ; or not
      (when (search-forward string nil t)
        (match-beginning 0)))))
```

It also depends on what you want to do after finding the position.  The documentation for [match data](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Simple-Match-Data.html) might be useful.  If you want to use the `match-data` afterwords, remove the call to `'save-match-data`.

Comment: `(buffer-string)` makes a copy of the buffer contents, so it's not practical for large buffers.

Comment: @Gilles - very true, I'll add a note indicating that, I should have originally.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The function corresponding to `strpos` in PHP, to search for a string inside another string, is `search` from the `cl` package:

```
(require 'cl)
(search needle haystack :start2 offset)
```

If you want to search a string inside a buffer, use `search-forward`. Since this changes the current buffer and the point inside that buffer, you need to wrap your function inside `save-excursion`; this is a common Emacs Lisp idiom. You should also wrap your function in `save-match-data`, so as not to interfere with the searches of whatever calls your code.

```
(save-match-data
  (save-excursion
    (set-buffer haystack)
    (goto-char (or offset (point-min)))
    (let ((pos (search-forward needle nil t)))
      ...)))
```